# how to use xpath to display certain values only

Tags: php, xml, xpath

```
<root>
    <a>
         <b>
              <c>cat</c>
              <d>dog</d>
              <e>elephant</e>
         </b>
    </a>
    <a>
         <b>
              <c>bat</c>
              <d>koala</d>
              <e>iguana</e>
         </b>
    </a>
</root>

$query = "//a/b/c[contains('cat', .)]";

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    //Trying to echo cat and the <d> tag here
    //Expected output "cat" and "dog" only (if possible to make dog as a variable)

}
```

im using xpath to find the keywords.i have use the query variable to find the information which contains the word "cat" from the XML file.

1. im now having problem on how to display the cat node in the foreach function. it found cat but it doesnt display the cat data
2. how do i display the other notes which is inside , for example used the query to find "cat", how do i display "dog" as well. this same goes for bat, if i put the keyword bat, how do i display koala.

thanks

Comment: you just use `echo` to output it

Comment: i tried to echo '/a/b/c: ',$entry,"\n"; but it doesnt show the cat

Comment: you use xpath from simpleXML, right?

Comment: $xmlStr = file_get_contents('animal.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);                                                           i could also use    $xml = simplexml_load_file("animal.xml");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use this xpath query to obtain desired child node:

```
$query = "//a/b/c[contains('cat', .)]";
```

Then, to get/echo its value and all siblings values, you can use this code:

```
foreach( $xml->xpath( $query ) as $node )
{
    echo $node->asXML() . PHP_EOL;
    echo $node->__toString() . PHP_EOL;

    foreach( $node->xpath('preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*') as $sibling )
    {
        echo $sibling->asXML() . PHP_EOL;
        echo $sibling->__toString() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

- `->asXML()` get complete XML node
- `->__toString()` get node as text (BTW, you can simply use `echo $node;` for this)
- xpath sub-query `preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling::*` get all preceding/following node siblings.

If you want obtain only `<e>` sibling, replace above xpath sub-query with:

```
preceding-sibling::e | following-sibling::e
```

Or — if you are not interested in returning ‘cat’ — directly with this xpath query:

```
echo $xml->xpath( "//a/b/c[contains('cat', .)]/../e" )[0]->__toString();
// output: elephant
```

Comment: thank you so much, i was thinking about only using 1 foreach, turns out i needed 2 and i learn this new xpath 'preceding-sibling::* to retrieve the following node.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to do this - but here's a way that should work for you (will display all siblings of 'cat' in text):

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

  $catParent = $xml->xpath("a/b/c[contains(., 'cat')]/..")[0];

  foreach($catParent as $child){
    echo $child."<br>";
  }
?>
```

Or if you just want to show 'cat':

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

  $catText = (string)$xml->xpath("a/b/c[contains(., 'cat')]")[0];

  echo $catText;
?>
```

Comment: $catParent = $xml->xpath("a/b/c[contains(., 'cat')]/..")[0]; what does the [0] means ?  and if i just want one of the siblings how do i do that, for example the <d> tag only. is there a way to make <d> as 1 variable <e> as one variable.